# "the oxygen concentration" OR "oxygen concentration"

Tags: articles

SITUATION: I've carried out a thorough chemical analysis of Thing X. It underwent heating, cooling, bending - you name it. In conclusion, should I say:

*"No increase in **the oxygen concentration** implies that..."*

OR

*"No increase in **oxygen concentration** implies that..."*

Should the "oxygen concentration" here be a general phenomenon, or a quality specific for Thing X and its analysis?

Maybe both are OK? And the difference is a question of preference, that is whether I wish to sound academically accurate, or go out on a limb with it and claim to have discovered something universal?

Comment: I think  either is as good  as the other. And I think no one will discover an academic nuance when you have the article or not. But for me the normal thing would be: the oxygen concentration.

Comment: I would use the former when it is important to stress that it is the oxygen concentration rather than, let's say, the CO2 concentration. I think I'm more likely to use the latter in any other case.

Comment: Are you, Nico, a native speaker of English? BrE or AmE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherently both mean the same thing.

Stylistically, adding *the* gives a more specific air to the sentence.

> The oxygen concentration rises as the partial pressure of carbon dioxide decreases.
>
> Oxygen concentration rises as the partial pressure of carbon dioxide decreases.

The first example makes it sound like you are speaking of a specific example.

The second example makes it sound like a general rule.

In your example above, I would say that context makes it clear that you are speaking of at the specific case at hand, so the two are interchangeable.  You just need to decide stylistically how it sounds best to you.